# Compatibility assistance issue in window 7

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-7

After creating an installer whenever I am running my application (from installer) , I am getting program compatibility assistant message. To fix this issue I have added the below code in my manifest file. but still I am getting the same issue . I am facing this issues in  2 of my applications one is in vs2010 and other is in VS2005. Below code fixes the issue in VS2010 application. But for the other application , still the issue is present.

```
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
<security>
  <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <!-- UAC Manifest Options
        If you want to change the Windows User Account Control level replace the 
        requestedExecutionLevel node with one of the following.

    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />

        Specifying requestedExecutionLevel node will disable file and registry virtualization.
        If you want to utilize File and Registry Virtualization for backward 
        compatibility then delete the requestedExecutionLevel node.
    -->
    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
  </requestedPrivileges>
</security>
```

```
  <!-- If your application is designed to work with Windows 7, uncomment the following supportedOS node-->
  <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>

</application>
```

can any one help me in resolving the above mentioned problem

Regards,

Vidya

Comment: How did you create the installer?

Comment: I am not aware of that. I am working in a software firm. A seperate team is there to create installers. we are putting build goods in a common shared location and their team is taking the goods from the common folder and creating the installer.